# Chrome doesn't load pages, unless I kill it's process

Tags: google-chrome

I'm experiencing a bug or a problem when I use chrome version 25.0.1364.97 m in Windows 7, both of which are up to date (according to my About Chrome page/Windows Update program).

The symptoms are that, after a few minutes of browsing new pages don't load. Pages I'm currently on still seem to function properly, so for instance I can watch videos on youtube from a playlist, and I can still use chat if I have that page loaded, for instance. Closing and reopening chrome doesn't do anything, and it seems as though I need to kill the process from the task manager. Closing individual processes (i.e. the ones that chrome has started for it's tabs) doesn't help, and I have to kill the Process Tree of whichever process is the original one for the browser (I presume).

On reloading Chrome, it tried to restore my tabs, but it isn't able to restore the latest ones (it restores whatever was open, I presume, from before the loading issue started that session).

I don't experience this issue in Linux (or if I have I've not noticed it!).

How can I fix this/work around it?

Comment: Delete your current Chrome profile, load Chrome without any extensions, does this problem still happen?  Does this problem with some other browser?

Comment: @Ramhound Where is my Chrome profile? Will my profile be synced back, or will I loose all my presets etc?

Comment: I've found it can take a while (a minute or two) for some Chrome processes to finally close after closing the application itself. Also, do you have "Continue running background apps when Google Chrome is closed" checked in advanced settings?

Comment: @w3d I used to but I turned it off. It seems as though it's own now though. Let me restart chrome and see if it stays off.

Comment: @Pureferret - Where it is exactly depends on your operating system.  Besides the location is well documented.

Comment: Same problem here... chrome does not load ANY page, version: 25.0.1364.97 m. any solutions so far?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's too old for me to duplicate the issue if a new answer comes in.

Answer (score 1):

Usually seems to happen when you run out of free Ram and/or Fill up [or remove] your paging file. I find creating a temporary bookmarks folder and using the right-click bookmark all open tabs a useful precaution.

(Also an extension called Session buddy saves backup sessions every 10 minutes automatically, it can help. You should reboot your computer after this happens).

Answer (score 0):

I've heard of that before.

Uninstall Chrome, then reinstall it.

Comment: tried it, does not help...